# How to re-write text on a label in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

I'm developing a piece of code which requires a function that checks whether the inputs entered by the user, through an Entry box, is a valid integer, within a certain range, and although I have managed to get the program to output an error message up (through a label) every time the user inputs an invalid integer, instead of overwriting the text that has previously been there on the label, it just outputs another one, leaving the old error message there. How do I get it to overwrite/re-write a pre-existing label?

Here is my function so far:

```
def Entry_check():

ErrorMessage = Label(text = '', fg = 'red')
ErrorMessage.grid()

if a.get().isdigit():    #Let 'a' be entry #1
    if int(a.get()) < 1 or int(a.get()) > 10:
        ErrorMessage.config(text = 'This is invalid')
    else:
        Var1 = a.get()    #Var1 now assigned to value in entry #1
        if b.get().isdigit():    #Let 'b' be entry #2
            if int(b.get()) < 2 or int(b.get()) > 5:
                ErrorMessage.config(text = 'This is invalid')
            else:
                Var2 = b.get()    #Var2 now assigned to value in entry #2
        else:
            ErrorMessage.config(text = 'This is invalid')
else:
    ErrorMessage.config(text = 'This is invalid')
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `ErrorMessage['text'] = "new text"` or `ErrorMessage.config(text="new text")`

Comment: do you get error message ? Always show FULL error message in question. Where do you declare `IntError` ? what is `b` ?

Comment: There is no error message, and b, as annotated, is entry #2 (in the same way a is entry #1). And sorry for saying 'IntError', that is supposed to say 'ErrorMessage', which I have changed now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new Label is being created every time you do error checking, because this line:

```
ErrorMessage = Label(text = '', fg = 'red')
```

Executes every time you call `Entry_check`.

Move this line outside of the function so it is only created once. It's hard to say where exactly without seeing the rest of your code -- perhaps wherever you created all of the other widgets for your window.

(You should also move `ErrorMessage.grid()` along with it, for the sake of maintainability, but I don't think it's actively harmful where it is now)

Comment: It works perfectly now. Thank you so much! I have no clue how I could miss something like that.